# CREATE PROCEDURE statement results in (1 row(s) affected)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm running SQL Server 2012.

I have a create procedure statement:

```
USE [dbname]
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Test]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Test] 
AS
SELECT 1
```

When I run this with dbname equals one database, I get:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

When running it dbname equals another database on the same server, I get:

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

Obviously this is a database setting or something specific to the database, but I can't seem to find anything.  Does anyone know what is causing the difference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this the same query window? My guess is that one of the windows has issued `SET NOCOUNT ON`. Or these are two different servers and one of them has TF3640 enabled. Or the 1 row(s) affected is actually coming from a DDL trigger, since the code you've shown in the question shouldn't create that output in any database. (If your code actually executes the stored procedure, show *that* code.)

Comment: It is in the same query window, and it is the create I am running.  I'll check for any triggers.

Comment: It was a trigger- it's the same trigger in both dbs, but one of them has a SET NOCOUNT ON.

Answer (score 0):

This may be cause of DDL trigger existence. as you mentioned in your comments, one of the triggers has SET NO COUNT ON, which will be stops the message that shows the count of the number of rows affected by a Transact-SQL statement or stored procedure from being returned as part of the result set. if you comment it, or add it to the other trigger too, you will see the same results for both above mentioned scenarios.